# Undefined value. Trying to set ID with fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I can access the data directly via the API, and I can make the onClick display data so I know that it triggers. The fetch fails because the Id is undefined however I cannot work out why the id is never defined.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Film from './Film.js';


class Actor extends React.Component {

 state = {
    display:false, 
    data:[],
  }

 loadFilmDetails = () => {
   const url = "http://localhost/c/api/films?actor_id=" + this.props.details.actor_id
   fetch(url)
     .then( (response) => response.json() )
     .then( (data) => {
       this.setState({data:data.data})
     })
      .catch ((err) => {
        console.log("something went wrong ", err)
     }
   );
 }

 handleActorClick = (e) => {
   this.setState({display:!this.state.display})
   this.loadFilmDetails()
 }

 render() {

   let films = ""
   if (this.state.display) {
     films = this.state.data.map( (details, i) => (<Film key={i} details={details} />) )
   }

   return (
     <div>
       <h2 onClick={this.handleActorClick}>{this.props.details.first_name} {this.props.details.last_name}</h2>
       {films}
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default Actor;
```

If I do `console.log(this.prop.details)` I get an object with some data, but no actor_id.

How do I make it so that `const url = "http://localhost/a/api/films?actor_id=" + this.props.details.actor_id` actually sets a value to actor_id (which is currently always undefined).

Comment: How are you using your `Actor` component? It sounds like you are not passing through an object with `actor_id` on it in the `details` prop

Comment: can you post the output of `console.log(this.prop.details)`

Comment: "f I do console.log(this.prop.details) I get an object with some data, but no actor_id." - you've solved your problem. Make sure details prop has actor_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two issues :

1. Either you are not passing the props `details.actor_id` from the parent to `Actor` component correctly.
2. Or the Actor Component has rendered before the `props` were available to it that's why you are getting the `undefined`.

And if it is the second case. Then you must first use an additional check on before making an `fetch` call.

Try this code change, once or share your codesandbox link (for us to see what is going on)

```
 handleActorClick = (e) => {
   this.setState({display:!this.state.display});
   this.props.details.actor_id && this.loadFilmDetails();
 }
```

Comment: It was number 1. I was sending actor_id from the API.

Comment: Can you please create a codesandbox link for the project... and share the link with me :)

Comment: I have updated my Answer See once if this works...If not would like you to create one project in codesandbox use these components and share the link with me. I would love to see where the actual problem is and help you out :) Coz I am crazy about ReactJS

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort Imran. The problem was just that I didn't select the id Column in the SQL query from the database. Cheers.

Comment: Oh Boy !!! These things does happen.. So basically props was not coming correctly to our Actor component.  If my answer has been of any help to you, would appreciate if you accept it by clicking on the tick icon. If not that's perfectly fine too :) CHEERS MATE

Answer (score -1):

Your return should in cotes so it will be considered as string value like so :

```
return (
 '<div><h2 onClick="'+{this.handleActorClick}+'>'+{this.props.details.first_name}+ {this.props.details.last_name}+'</h2>'+
   {films}+
 '</div>' );
```